# show all employees from specific set of stores

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

My job is to cleanse the database from broken store records(records with missing data like a store name or streetname, database example below). However it turns out some of those records have employees linked to them so we can't just delete them.

Question: what kind of query do I need to make sure only the employees of those stores are shown?

I have three tables in which i need to work: user, department and store_users (store_users is a table in which all ID's are packed together to see which user_id belongs to which store_id.)

## Example of code

its most likely wrong but its to give some insight in what I am trying to accomplish.(its purely mysql at the moment)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    gebruiker
WHERE
    (SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            winkel_adresgegevens
        WHERE
            winkel_id IN (SELECT 
                    winkel_gebruikers_winkel_id
                FROM
                    winkel_gebruikers)
                AND (winkel_naam = '' OR winkel_straat = ''
                OR winkel_huisnummer = ''
                OR winkel_postcode = ''
                OR winkel_plaats = ''));
```

## database example

```
+--------+---------------+----------+------------+------------------+
|store_id|store_branch_id|store_name|store_street|store_streetnumber|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1    |     100       |  Jumbo   | Hilversum  |        14        |
|--------+---------------+----------+------------+------------------|
|   2    |     150       |  Lidl    | Kerkelanden|        24        |
|--------+---------------+----------+------------+------------------|
|   3    |     105       |          | Loosdrecht |                  |
|--------+---------------+----------+------------+------------------|
|   4    |     200       |  Coop    |            |        14        |
+--------+---------------+----------+------------+------------------+
```

hence the question: only show employees from the broken records. (the ones with missing data, see store_name, store_street and store_streetnumber)

Comment: can you show us a sample table schema ?

Comment: It's sometimes useful to translate the query as well as the question.

Comment: Please define `broken store records`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE : This is what you want

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees 
WHERE store_name IS NULL OR store_street IS NULL OR  store_streetnumber IS NULL ;
```

Comment: what does the (1,2,3) stand for?